# Matlab Transparency violation error while the code is correct

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am using the Matlab parallel toolbox to do parallel computing. I've doubled check the variable definition of the code, and it follows the requirements of parfor command. However, Matlab still told me that "Transparency Violation Error," could you help me figure out this issue?

Here is the source code.

```
load Wind80.mat
Wspeed_80 = Wind80;
TotalLoc = 4000;
Nloc = 5; % no of loc of each run
maxrun = ceil(TotalLoc/Nloc);
StrInfo.Pstr = 1; 
StrInfo.Tstr = 0:4:72;
tic
parfor run = 1:maxrun
   WT1 = [];
   WT2 = [];
   [WT1, WT2] = CompWTGenFun(run, Nloc, TotalLoc, StrInfo);
   filenm = ['ResultPara' num2str(StrInfo.Pstr) 'Run' num2str(run) '.mat' ];
   save(filenm, 'WT1', 'WT2', '-mat');
   clear WT1 WT2
end
toc
```

Comment: Not a solution, but some general improvements: Initializing `WT1` and `WT2` to empty matrices has no purpose, and `clear WT1 WT2` is a pessimization (`clear` will typically slow down your code).

Comment: Regarding the problem: I think it might be because MATLAB cannot tell that `filenm` will be different for each loop iteration. Try generating the file names outside the loop, then in the loop `save(filenm{run},...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved by moving 'clear WT1 WT2' and save function in the subfunction of the parfor loop.

Comment: It seems Edric’s answer helped you then. If so, please click on the grey check mark to the left of the answer, o mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the `save` function within a `parfor` loop, as this will result in a [transparency violation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/transparency.html). Transparency violations occur when a function needs to look into (or modify) its calling workspace. Unfortunately, `save` does this - in your code, you give the `save` command the *names* of the variables you want to save, and the `save` implementation attempts to extract the values from its calling workspace (i.e. the body of the `parfor` loop).

The workaround is to hide the call to `save` inside a separate function, in other words, you need something like this:

```
parfor ...
    mySave(filenm, WT1, WT2);
end
# ...
function mySave(filenm, WT1, WT2)
    save(filenm, 'WT1', 'WT2', '-mat');
end
```

This works because the transparency constraint only applies to the code directly present in the body of the `parfor` loop.

As mentioned in the comments, the `clear` command you have is not necessary, and would again cause a transparency violation.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved by moving 'clear WT1 WT2' and save function in the subfunction of the parfor loop.